# Is there a way to monitor progress of uploaded to Azure cloud server via PHP?

Tags: php, azure, upload

I'm working on a project that processes some files on the server at the user's request, then uploads the resulting ZIP file as a blob to Azure for storage.  A few cases involve extremely large files which take about an hour to upload.  It would be helpful if I could at any random moment run a *separate* process that queries Azure for the upload progress while the main process on the local server is still preoccupied with uploading the file.

Is there a way to do this in PHP?  (If it's of any help, this project is running on Phalcon.)

Comment: Please edit to show your code, and also please be specific about where you're uploading to (azure blob? file share? something else?)

Comment: The _upload_ code isn't really relevant to this question since what I'm looking for is how to run a _separate_ process that queries Azure to find out how much of the upload it has received at any given moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Is there a way to monitor progress of uploaded to Azure cloud server via PHP?
```

I don't think it's possible because uploading file is a single task and even though internally the file is split into multiple chunks and these chunks get uploaded, the code actually wait for the entire task to finish.

Comment: My thinking is that while one process on the server is stuck on the action of uploading (ran by a queued cron job), the user's web browser could request a status update, which would call a _separate_ process that queries _Azure_ to find out how much of the file has reached Azure.  E.g., a 30gb file is being upload and its size is recorded in the local database, then querying Azure about the file returns "10gb received so far," which could be mathed on the local server into "10/30gb uploaded" or "33% uploaded."